# Simple rot13 encoder in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am looking for a simple way to encode an inputted text into Rot13. I am hitting a brick wall at the stage of being able to separate out words into individual characters and integers so that I can change each one and output the result. I can do it with single letters using a simple if statement listed bellow but if anyone can help with a way of doing it for whole words I would be very appreciative.

```
If kInput = "a" then kOutput = "n"
```

Thanks, Kai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like people are giving good answers to this but here's my try at it.

```
Dim input As String = "This is a Test!! Guvf vf n Grfg!!"
Dim result As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

For Each ch As Char In input

    If (Not Char.IsLetter(ch)) Then
        result.Append(ch)
        Continue For
    End If

    Dim checkIndex As Integer = Asc("a") - (Char.IsUpper(ch) * -32)
    Dim index As Integer = ((Asc(ch) - checkIndex) + 13) Mod 26

    result.Append(Chr(index + checkIndex))

Next

Console.WriteLine(result.ToString())
```

EDIT: improved to remove need for uppercase check. This will properly handle case and special characters with only 1 if statement inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're making this way harder than it has to be. No need to separate words, etc, and definitely no need for a large If/Else block:

```
Public Function Rot13(ByVal input As String) As String
    Dim result As Char() = input.ToCharArray()

    For i As Integer = 0 To result.Length - 1
        Dim temp As Integer = Asc(result(i))
        Select Case temp
           Case 65 to 77, 97 To 109 'A - M
               result(i) = Chr(temp + 13)
           Case 78 to 90, 110 To 122 'N - Z
               result(i) = Chr(temp - 13)
        End Select
    Next i

    Return New String(result)
End Function
```

Note that this was entered directly into the browser window and is completely untested.

Answer (score 0):

Just call it once to encode, call it again to decode.

```
Private Function ROT13_Encode(ByVal Input As String) As String
Dim chrs As Char() = Input.ToCharArray()
Dim ReturnString As String = ""
Dim CharInt As Integer

For Each Chr As Char In chrs
    CharInt = Asc(Chr)
    If CharInt >= 65 And CharInt <= 77 Then 'A-M
        CharInt += 13
    ElseIf CharInt >= 78 And CharInt <= 90 Then 'M-Z
        CharInt -= 13
    ElseIf CharInt >= 97 And CharInt <= 109 Then 'a-m
        CharInt += 13
    ElseIf CharInt >= 110 And CharInt <= 122 Then 'm-z
        CharInt -= 13
    End If
    ReturnString &= ChrW(CharInt)

Next

Return ReturnString
End Function
```