# Vb.net Changing all letters in string to different letters

Tags: vb.net, string, variables

I am creating a bit of code that takes the users input(which is a string) and changes every letter to the 13 letter form it in the alphabet. But I have made it to see the length on the text. But I don't know how to add 1 to a variable every time it changes a letter to the 13th on along in the alphabet.

```
Dim looped As Integer
Dim length As Integer
Dim text As String
Dim newtext As String


Sub Main()

    Console.WriteLine("Enter some text")
    text = Console.ReadLine

    looped = 0
    text = LCase(text)
    length = Len(text)

    For counter = 1 To 25 Step 1

        text = text.Replace("a", "n")
        text = text.Replace("b", "o")
        text = text.Replace("c", "p")
        text = text.Replace("d", "q")
        text = text.Replace("e", "r")
        text = text.Replace("f", "s")
        text = text.Replace("g", "t")
        text = text.Replace("h", "u")
        text = text.Replace("i", "v")
        text = text.Replace("j", "w")
        text = text.Replace("k", "x")
        text = text.Replace("l", "y")
        text = text.Replace("m", "z")
        text = text.Replace("n", "a")
        text = text.Replace("o", "b")
        text = text.Replace("p", "c")
        text = text.Replace("q", "d")
        text = text.Replace("r", "e")
        text = text.Replace("s", "f")
        text = text.Replace("t", "g")
        text = text.Replace("u", "h")
        text = text.Replace("v", "i")
        text = text.Replace("w", "j")
        text = text.Replace("x", "k")
        text = text.Replace("y", "l")
        text = text.Replace("z", "m")

    Next

    Console.WriteLine(text)
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to loop through text and "replace" each char separately. You may find this bit of code useful: `Convert.ToInt32(ch)`

Comment: 1) There's a bit of a problem there. Say your text was "a". So it gets replaced with "n". And then a few lines down that "n" gets replaced with "a". 2) Hint: search for "ROT13".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple rot13 encoder in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016727/simple-rot13-encoder-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a simple "encryption" method. If you only want lower case a-z.
By adding 1, I guess you mean incrementing to the next character, if you want to do this I would use a character code of some sort.
I would do it this way (quick mock up):

```
    Dim LetterArray As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" 'ANYTHING you want
    Dim NewLetterArray As String = ""
    Dim LetterStep As Integer = 13 'Can be from 0 to 13 in your scenario.
    For Each CurrentLetter As Char In LetterArray
        If (Asc(CurrentLetter) + LetterStep) > Asc("z") Then
            NewLetterArray = NewLetterArray & Chr(Asc(CurrentLetter) + LetterStep - (LetterStep * 2))
        Else
            NewLetterArray = NewLetterArray & Chr(Asc(CurrentLetter) + LetterStep)
        End If
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(NewLetterArray)
```

Comment: Sorry for lack of explanation. As you are incrementing by 13 and there are only 26 characters in the a-z alphabet, the if function check if you are going over the ASCII character code for "z" with your step(current letter +13). If it is then go backwards with the step*2 and you will get the character you need.

If you mark the location in the if statement for debugging in visual studio, this should give you a better understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

This solution supports upper case letters and also punctuation

```
Private Function rot13(input As String) As String
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    For Each c In input
        Dim a = Asc(c)
        Select Case a
            Case 97 To 122
                ' lower case letters a to z
                ' a - 84 = a - 97 + 13
                sb.Append(Chr(((a - 84) Mod 26) + 97))
            Case 65 To 90
                ' upper case letters A to Z
                ' a - 52 = a - 65 + 13
                sb.Append(Chr(((a - 52) Mod 26) + 65))
            Case Else
                ' all other characters, i.e. punctuation
                sb.Append(c)
        End Select
    Next c
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

usage:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim input = "The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog!"
    Console.WriteLine("original:")
    Console.WriteLine(input)

    input = rot13(input)
    Console.WriteLine("rot13(original):")
    Console.WriteLine(input)

    input = rot13(input)
    Console.WriteLine("rot13(rot13(original)):")
    Console.WriteLine(input)

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

output:

> original:
>   
> The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog!
>   
> rot13(original):
>   
> Gur Dhvpx Oebja Sbk Whzcf Bire Gur Ynml Qbt!
>   
> rot13(rot13(original)):
>   
> The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog!

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it in this way

```
set x = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
encrypt = inputbox("type text om te versleutelen")
x.Run "%windir%\notepad"
wscript.sleep 1000
x.sendkeys encode(encrypt)

function encode(s)
For i = 1 To Len(s)
newtxt = Mid(s, i, 1)
newtxt = Chr(Asc(newtxt)+13)
coded = coded & newtxt
Next
encode = coded
End Function
```

here the code makes a inputbox than does +13 and after that it will type the message

Answer (score -1):

If you are referring to your variable `looped` which you initialise to 0, then you should increment it in each iteration:

```
Dim looped As Integer
Dim length As Integer
Dim text As String
Dim newtext As String

Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter some text")
    text = Console.ReadLine

    looped = 0
    text = LCase(text)
    length = Len(text)

    For counter = 1 To 25 Step 1
        text = text.Replace("a", "n")
        text = text.Replace("b", "o")
        text = text.Replace("c", "p")
        text = text.Replace("d", "q")
        text = text.Replace("e", "r")
        text = text.Replace("f", "s")
        text = text.Replace("g", "t")
        text = text.Replace("h", "u")
        text = text.Replace("i", "v")
        text = text.Replace("j", "w")
        text = text.Replace("k", "x")
        text = text.Replace("l", "y")
        text = text.Replace("m", "z")
        text = text.Replace("n", "a")
        text = text.Replace("o", "b")
        text = text.Replace("p", "c")
        text = text.Replace("q", "d")
        text = text.Replace("r", "e")
        text = text.Replace("s", "f")
        text = text.Replace("t", "g")
        text = text.Replace("u", "h")
        text = text.Replace("v", "i")
        text = text.Replace("w", "j")
        text = text.Replace("x", "k")
        text = text.Replace("y", "l")
        text = text.Replace("z", "m")

        ' Increment "looped" here:
        looped = looped + 1

    Next

    Console.WriteLine(text)
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Comment: it tried it but it only changes the fifth letter of the string to the 13th letter along in the alpahbet

Comment: Its unclear what you are using `looped` for here...(?) -- You do realise that in your `text` variable, you are replacing "a" with "n", and then replacing "n" back to "a" again....

Comment: I was meant to remove looped variable. I was trying to make a code maker that would get every letter and turn it into  the 13th letter along in the allaphbet

Comment: Unsure why this was downvoted - it is an answer to a somewhat unclear question i know. I do think that any downvote should be accompanied by a comment explaning the downvote... (hello meta)

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I guess you got downvoted because your answer only tells him to increment a variable that he's never even using, thus doing so won't solve his problem. -- I do agree with you that people should explain their downvotes, though.

Comment: Indeed Vincent, as the question was rather ambiguous and only requested how to "...But I don't know how to add 1 to a variable..." so it was easy to assume OP was referring to some loop counter.... a bit pants really. I think the hard part for developers is knowing what to search for, what to ask in a succinct manner, it's difficult sometimes so I understand OPs position, and take it on the chin that my answer was pretty pointless after all.